# Is it possible to grab a (yield) input from a coroutine?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm providing some framework code which uses coroutines to allow remote control of some tasks.

Currently I ask my devs to write something like this in the business logic:

```
def do_stuff():
    return 999

def do_some_operations():
    remote_input = (yield)
    if not remote_input:
       raise RuntimeError, "stop this crazy thing"
    else:
       yield do_stuff()

    remote_input = (yield)
    if not remote_input:
       raise RuntimeError, "stop this crazy thing"
    else:
       yield do_stuff()

    # ..etc

coro = do_some_operations()
next(coro)
keepgoing = True
while 1:
   coro.send(keepgoing)
   print next(coro)
keepgoing = not keepgoing
```

I'd like to give then a convenience function that handled the boilerplate checking:

```
   def check_cancellation():
       if not (yield) raise RuntimeError, "user requested stop"
```

However that's not doable  since `check_cancellation()` is actually an entirely separate coroutine.  What I'd like to do is be able to effectively get access to the coroutine's yield inside of `check_cancellation()` -- the sort of thing I might try by looking up one stack frame except I the `yield` is a statement so it's not actually part of the coro's frame.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: The example is now runnable, although making it runnable adds no information to the actual question which is asking for a suggestion on technique rather than a bug fix.